# UILabel Position not change inside UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I'm trying to change the position of a UILabel contained inside a custom UITableViewCell, but it doesn't move. I have auto layout enabled.

```
- (void)updateLayout
{
    NSArray* comp = [self.accessibilityHint componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    if (comp.count > 1)
    {
    CGRect rect = _imageViewT.frame;
    rect.origin.x = 20 * comp.count;
    rect.size.width = 44.0;
    [_imageViewT setFrame:rect];
    [_imageConstraint setConstant:_imageViewT.frame.origin.x-8];

    rect = _lableT.frame;
    rect.origin.x = _imageViewT.frame.size.width+_imageViewT.frame.origin.x+8;
    rect.size.width = self.frame.size.width-rect.origin.x-40;
    [_lableT setFrame:rect];
    //[_imageConstraint setConstant:_imageViewT.frame.origin.x-8];


}
else
{
    CGRect rect = _imageViewT.frame;
    rect.origin.x = 10;
    rect.size.width = 43.0;
    [_imageViewT setFrame:rect];
    [_imageConstraint setConstant:2];

    rect = _lableT.frame;
    rect.origin.x = 62;
    rect.size.width = self.frame.size.width-rect.origin.x-40;
    [_lableT setFrame:rect];
}
```

}

I am calling update method from cellForRowAtIndexPath.
self.accessibilityHint contain string like aa/bb/cc, aa/cc

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewCell will layout subviews in `layoutSubviews:` after  `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, so your layout will be reset in cell's layoutSubviews.
You should move your layout code from cellForRowAtIndexPath: to cell's layoutSubviews.

Comment: Yes I have did the same. It is working fine. But now when I select any row, it change the position again.

Or When I rotate my device it change the position again.

Comment: Yes, =layoutSubvies= will be called several times if the cell thinks that it should relayout itself, such as frame changed, setSelected:. So if you put  your layout code in layoutSubvies, you must make sure that it works right all the time. Maybe you have to create some property to identify the current state for the cell, then you could make different layout base on this property.

Comment: Can you please let me know how I can get the current state of cell.

Comment: If I don't call [super layoutSubviews] than it is working fine but in that case UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark not showing in correct position

Comment: Yes, you should call [super layoutSubviews], cell will layout the contentView/textLabel/detailTextLabel/accessoryView/backgroundView/... in super method. I said "state of cell" mean the "comp.count > 1" or not, not the system state of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Set label's autoresizingMask property, i always use it with cell's subviews.